# Display cell array contents in another output format

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I am searching for a way display cell array contents other than with `celldisp` that gives me an output like the example below:

```
celldisp(stuff)
```

and a typical output:

```
stuff{1} =
    10    70    20    50    50    90    90    30    30    60
stuff{2} =
    80    50    50    50    30    90    40    60    50    60    20    20
stuff{3} =
    20    90    10    80    20    30    30    70
```

I would prefer to print it out like this instead:

```
10    70    20    50    50    90    90    30    30    60
80    50    50    50    30    90    40    60    50    60    20    20
20    90    10    80    20    30    30    70
```

Is this possible? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to use [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), which automatically pads entries with a space if no format specifier is provided. You can take advantage of this behavior with a looped [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) call.

For example:

```
stuff{1} = [10, 70, 20, 50, 50, 90, 90, 30, 30, 60];
stuff{2} = [80, 50, 50, 50, 30, 90, 40, 60, 50, 60, 20, 20];
stuff{3} = [20, 90, 10, 80, 20, 30, 30, 70];

for ii = 1:numel(stuff)
    fprintf('%s\n', num2str(stuff{ii}));
end
```

Which produces:

```
>> iheartSO
10  70  20  50  50  90  90  30  30  60
80  50  50  50  30  90  40  60  50  60  20  20
20  90  10  80  20  30  30  70
```

You can also utilize the equivalent [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) call if you want to be all compact and stuff:

```
cellfun(@(x)fprintf('%s\n', num2str(x)), stuff);
```